# OpenVPN Is connected, but doesn't work

Tags: networking, openvpn, routing

I have server running OpenVPN, I created a .ovpn file and used it to connect to server from my phone. OpenVPN says, that it's connection.
Server also says, that it's client, BUT. In Russia it is some websites blocked, and I just tried to connect to one of them, but it still doesn't works(It's a blank page with message from my internet provider). 
It means, that connect doesn't go through VPN server, but instead through my provider network.
So how can I check where is the problem and maybe it's common problem and It's easy fix of that
EDIT 1
This problem is probably caused by DNS leaking, so I'm a bit closer to solve this

Comment: Server is hosted by Hetzner, so it's in Germany and running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Client Config File

```
block-outside-dns
```